# vue.js force update input element not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have an input element that bind with v-model to a item value, I want to limit the user input to just type numeric value on range between **0** to **10**, I was tried this thing before(add @input and check the input value to keep it in range)

my code is like this:

```
<v-text-field @input="checkItem" v-model="item"></v-text-field>

checkItem(val) {
      if(parseInt(val) < 1) {
        this.item = 1;
      } else if(parseInt(val) >10) {
        this.item = 10;
      }
    }
```

**Problem**
after first time we type number out of range the function works great and keep it in range but when we type out of range number again the element didn't update because the new item value is the same as the old item value! to solve this I try to use forceUpdate and the `$forceUpdate()` not work!!!

**for example**

- if user type anything between range number into input, because it's in range everything is ok;
- but if user type 0 or any number outside of range, on the first time item value change to 1 if value was under 1 but if again type any negative value because the item value last time was changed to 1 when we set it to 1 again nothing happening on the view and the element value was not updated.

**The main question is how to force vue to update this input field value?**

Comment: Have you tried watching for changes using a `watch` method rather than binding to input? Modifying the model data in an input hook is not intended usage of `v-model`

Comment: @rh16 if you mean use :value to bind item value from data object and change the item on the watch from input change, I have to say yes I was tried this before and got the same problem(the view part is not update because of the value is not changed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  <div><input type="number" v-model="item"></input></div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ranges",

  data() {
    return {
      item: Number,
      error: String
    };
  },

  watch: {
    item(newVal, lastVal) {
      if (newVal > 10) this.item = 10
      if (newVal < 1) this.item = 1
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Here using the watcher you can do that validation

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I don't want to show a message to user, I want to replace the user input value with the correct one just when user is typing(the current code update the data object value but not update the view part of component, because the value is the same as before on data object then vue thinks no change was happened)

Comment: @Mojtaba i've just updated the code to acomplish what you said, let me know if that is what you were looking for.

Comment: Absolutely right and thank you
But why sometimes something wrong with the second condition and accepts it to be zero ?!?

Comment: Actually i have never used before the @input callback, may be there is the issue, i recommend you to use better in this cases watch methods or computed ones

Comment: And the main update problem was not solved!, when we try to type 0 into input first time it's update to 1 but after that the value on the vue-devtool is 1 but on the screen input element have the 0 value! and also if we type max value like 1000 give the same problem. then we need to rerender the input element to keep it update

Comment: Are you sure ? take a look here with those examples you gave me . https://codesandbox.io/s/2vl035z37y  i tested there and works well

Answer (score 1):

The only way to force the reactivity when the the final result is always the same, is to re-render the component for it to reflect the changes by updating its `key`.

[Reference link here.](https://michaelnthiessen.com/force-re-render/)

I have forked the [sample Vue project](https://codesandbox.io/s/2vl035z37y)  from [mdiaz00147](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2718745/mdiaz00147), and modify into
[this](https://codesandbox.io/s/kh4mr?file=/src/App.vue), and I think it works as the author intended it to be.

Solution Code modified from [mdiaz00147](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2718745/mdiaz00147) 's code snippet

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input :key="inputKey" v-model="item" @change="checkItem" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ranges",

  data() {
    return {
      item: null,
      inputKey: 0,
    };
  },

  methods: {
    checkItem() {
      if (parseInt(this.item) < 1) {
        this.item = 1;
      } else if (parseInt(this.item) > 10) {
        this.item = 10;
      }
      this.inputKey += 1;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: This does work. The only drawback is that the input looses focus when the key changes.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple workaround for me to be the following when validating.
These are the steps:

1. simply set the value to be the wrong un validated value first and **only set it on blur or change** (not input because it will auto-blur)
2. then run your validation logic and update the data.item (this will now work since it knows it changed)

in code all you have to change:

```
checkItem(val) {
  this.item = val; // add this
  if(parseInt(val) < 1) {
    this.item = 1;
  } else if(parseInt(val) >10) {
    this.item = 10;
  }
}
```

Just make sure you only pass the value up or "use" the value after validation completes, expect the value to be outside of your validation parameters in watches and computes.